# how can i find the 2nd largest number from given number without using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, types, numbers

I have some code to get that could you guys help me to get the remaining code.....

```
public class SumOfGivenInt {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num=6789123,lastvalue=0;
    while(num>0){

        int reminder=num%10;
        int copy=reminder;

// I think here some code need to write........

        System.out.println(reminder);
         lastvalue=lastvalue*10+reminder;
         num/=10;
    }
}

}
```

My idea is to copy the reminder and compare that reminder with the previous value then we will get the correct answer. how can i reach my requirement by using my logic.......

Comment: `if(copy==copy-1) {`will never be true

Comment: your question is unclear. Do you want to select the largest number from "6789123". Is answer 9?

Comment: then what can i do. please suggest me.

Comment: There are two ways 1) Sort nos 2)use 2 variables.

Comment: how please add code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code a little bit in order to find the second largest number from a given number. You need two while loop to do this. The first while loop is to get the largest number and the second while loop is to get the next largest number. Hope you will understand the logic of how to do this.

```
    int num=6789123,lastvalue=0;
    int largest = 0;
    int secondLargest = 0;
    while(num>0){

        int reminder=num%10;
        if(reminder > largest)          //get the largest number
        {
            largest = reminder;
        }

        System.out.println(reminder);
         lastvalue=lastvalue*10+reminder;
         num/=10;
    }

    num=6789123;
    while(num>0){
        int reminder=num%10;
        if(reminder > secondLargest)    //get the second largest number
        {
            if(reminder != largest)
            {
                secondLargest = reminder;
            }
        }
         lastvalue=lastvalue*10+reminder;
         num/=10;
    }


    System.out.println(largest);
    System.out.println(secondLargest);
```

Comment: Let me know if this helps